# SSRS Report matrix

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, subreport

I want to display a graph with a variable number of curves (that I get from a dataset) :

So I can have this :

---

### Trend 1 | Tag 1.1 | Unit 1 |

### Trend 1 | Tag 1.2 | Unit 2 |

### Trend 2 | Tag 2.1 | Unit 1 |

### Trend 2 | Tag 2.2 | Unit 2 |

### Trend 2 | Tag 2.3 | Unit 3 |

I Want to display this in a matrix with a group on Trend name to have somethning like this :

---

### Trend 1 | Graph SubReport      |

### Trend 2 | Graph Subreport      |

In the subreport I have Tag1Name, Tag2Name, ... Tag10Name (It was designed like this and I cannot change it :/)

So I have to pass as a parameter to the subreport tag names and I don't find a way to to do this, because when I do it "normally" I have only the first Tag (Tag 1.1 for trend1 and Tag 2.1 for Trend 2).

Do you have any idea ?

I use SSRS 2008 (NOT R2 - so no lookup feature).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a report with column groups containing subreports with graphs?

Comment: Hi, I don't have a column group, I have only a row group by Trend name.